# jpa spring boot - hibernate insert slow

Tags: database, hibernate, spring-boot, insert, spring-data-jpa

I have three lists of entities that i'm trying to save to the database.

in total it's about 1000 entites it have to persist.

```
entityRepo.save(EntityList);
```

However this takes 4-5 minutes to complete. - And i noticed its doing some selects before the inserts, I assume it's hibernate dirty checking to see if it needs to update or insert.

Anyway to disable this and improve the speed of hibernate insert ?

been looking into flushing but not sure how to do it when saving an entire list at once ?

Comment: Don't use save with the list but iterate yourself. Switch on batch inserts, and when looping each x (for instance 50) object flush and clear en `entity manager`. Every time an object is persisted hibernate dirty checks *all* the entities in the first level cache, with 1 entity this isn't noticeable, but with 1000 it ramps it pretty fast. limiting it to 50 and flush/clear in between helps with that.

Answer (score 1):

If all the entities are the same then you should turn on batch-inserts. Here's a couple of articles to get you started. It's primarily just adding some configuration.

http://memorynotfound.com/hibernate-jpa-batch-insert-batch-update-example/
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/batch/Batching.html

Answer (score 0):

You are correct when you say that dirty checking is causing reads from the database. If you use a standard Hibernate `Session` to persist your entities they will be managed by Hibernate as normal.

If you wish to avoid this the easiest approach is probably to open a `StatelessSession` and use `org.hibernate.StatelessSession.insert`. This does not use a first level cache and so does not need to dirty check entities.

You can achieve this by calling `SessionFactory#withStatelessOptions` to obtain an instance of `StatelessSessionBuilder`. You can then call `org.hibernate.StatelessSessionBuilder.openStatelessSession`.